# Microsoft SQL Server MAX return

Tags: mysql, sql, select, max, where-clause

I'm trying to return the first_name, last_name, and height of the tallest female(s) in a table.

```
SELECT height, gender
FROM students
WHERE gender = 'F'
ORDER BY height ASC
```

I did this to find out what the tallest female height was, which is (197) for two females. I tried getting SQL to show ONLY the two females at 197 with their first_name, last_name, and height but I have only got the code to return the value 197 with 1 row affected. It should be 2 rows affected with the first_name, last_name, and height of the two highest females. How can I fix my code?

```
SELECT MAX(height)
FROM  students
WHERE gender = 'F'
GROUP BY patient_height, first_name, last_name, gender
ORDER BY patient_height DESC
```

This returns values that are NOT MAX(height) and MAX(height), what can I do to fix this error?

Comment: Use two SELECTs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, MySQL does not support the `WITH TIES` syntax like SQL Server.

One solution is to use a correlated subquery, as demonstrated by Gordon Linoff. In MysQL 8.0, you can also use window function `RANK()`:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        s.*,
        rank() over(order by patient_height desc) rn
    from students s
    where gender = 'F'
) x
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use a subquery:

```
select s.*
from students s
where s.gender = 'F' and
      s.height = (select max(s2.height)
                  from students s2
                  where s2.gender = 'F'
                 );
```